# Get the means of sub groups of means in R

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, mean

I'm a newbie of R and I don't know how to get R calculate the means of a subgroups of means which are the means of a subgroup themselves. I'll explain clearer.

I have a data frame like this:

```
GROUP WORD WLN
1     1    4
1     1    3
1     1    3
1     2    2
1     2    2
1     2    3
2     3    1
2     3    1
2     3    2
2     4    1
2     4    1
2     4    1
...   ...  ...
```

but the real one has a total of 5 groups and 25 words (5 words each group; every word has being assigned a number from 1 to 4 by 5 subjects...).

I need to get the means of WLN for every word and I can do that easily with a loop and save the results in a vector; but then I need a vector with the means of these means according to the group which the words belong to... So I need the means of means of words of the group 1, then of group 2, etc... (I don't know if I'm making it clear).

How can I get this without doing it one group by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With base, using `aggregate`

```
> aggregate(WLN~GROUP+WORD, mean, data=df)
  GROUP WORD      WLN
1     1    1 3.333333
2     1    2 2.333333
3     2    3 1.333333
4     2    4 1.000000
```

where `df` is @Metrics' data.

Another alternative is using `summaryBy` from doBy package

```
> library(doBy)
> summaryBy(WLN~GROUP+WORD, FUN=mean, data=df)
  GROUP WORD WLN.mean
1     1    1 3.333333
2     1    2 2.333333
3     2    3 1.333333
4     2    4 1.000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume df is your dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(GROUP = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), WORD = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L), WLN = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), .Names = c("GROUP", "WORD", "WLN"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

**Plyr solution**

```
install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(GROUP,WORD),summarize, meanwln=mean(WLN))
 GROUP WORD  meanwln
1     1    1 3.333333
2     1    2 2.333333
3     2    3 1.333333
4     2    4 1.000000
```

**Data.table solution:**

```
install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
df<-data.table(df)
setkey(df,GROUP,WORD)
df[,list(meanwln=mean(WLN)),by="GROUP,WORD"]

 GROUP WORD  meanwln
1:     1    1 3.333333
2:     1    2 2.333333
3:     2    3 1.333333
4:     2    4 1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you, this works good for the means of words, then I suppose I have to do that again for the means of groups, right?

Comment: No, it already gave you the mean of words by Groups. As you see, for first group and first word, the mean is 3.33 and for the second group and first word the mean is 2.33 and so on.

Comment: I'm afraid they are not the (only) mean values I want. Isn't it the mean in line 1 (3.33) the mean of the WLNs of the word 1? and the mean in line 2 (2.33) the mean of the WLNs of the word 2? and so on (which seems to me to be different from what you say here)?

Comment: My apology. I was reading the rownames. 3.33 is the mean of WORD1 for group1 1, 2.33 is mean of word2 for group 1 and so on.

Comment: Ok, and that's fine but I need also the mean for group one (i.e. mean(meanwl[GROUP==1}) and for group two (mean(meanwl[GROUP==2}). But how can I get this automatically with the means of the words? I mean, I need the means of word 1, 2, , 3, 4, n... and then the means of group 1, 2, 3, 4, n ...

Comment: Actually, I notice now I can just re-use the code above to get the means of group and it will be fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: `ddply(df,.(GROUP),summarize, meanwln=mean(WLN))` for group mean and `ddply(df,.(WORD),summarize, meanwln=mean(WLN))` for WORD mean

Answer (score 1):

with base:

```
with(df,tapply(WLN,list(GROUP,WORD),mean))
```

**Edit:**

If you also want row- and colmeans for the table above, you could do something like this:

```
x <- with(df,tapply(WLN,list(GROUP,WORD),mean))
addmargins(x, margin = seq_along(dim(x)), FUN = mean, quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I suppose that after using that code I have to run another code to get the mean of words by groups, right? I thought that could be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

And now dplyr is even better...

```
require(dplyr)
tmp <- group_by(df, WORD)
df1 <- summarise(tmp, 
   count = n(), 
   mWLN = mean(WLN, na.rm = TRUE))
df1
```