# Applying a function to a combination of column values

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, multiple-columns

Here is a data frame, with P, G, A:

```
P   G  A    
C2 28 R0
C2 35 R1
C2 30 R0
C2 33 R0
C2 30 R0
C7 31 R1
C7 25 R1
C7 23 R1
C7 28 R0
C7 22 R0
C8 22 R1
C8 23 R1
C8 25 R0
C8 30 R1
C8 33 R0
C8 27 R0
```

Is there a simple way to get mean of G for each A within each P? That is for C2, I want the mean of G for A == R0. I can only use aggregate for one grouping, but not knowing how to manage combined two or more groupings.

Comment: `aggregate(G ~ P + A, dat, mean)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the means of sub groups of means in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944668/get-the-means-of-sub-groups-of-means-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You can supply aggregate with multiple columns, see aggregate example.